# Adding ArrayList to TreeMap within a while cycle

Tags: java, arraylist, treemap

I'm retrieving data from a table in a database and add the whole row to a `TreeMap`.

I'm using the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> listaValores = new ArrayList();
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList> tmValores = new TreeMap<>();
```

(...)

```
    while (rs.next()) 
    {
        listaValores.clear();
        for(int i=2; i<=ncolunas; i++)
        {
            listaValores.add(rs.getString(i));
        }
        tmValores.put(rs.getInt(1), listaValores);   
    }
```

My `TreeMap` keys are inserted fine but the values are always repeated as the values from the last line as a result from the SELECT * FROM Table query.

So if my table is:

```
id | name | last name | 
1  | joe  | lewis     | 
2  | mark | spencer   | 
3  | mike | carter    | 
4  | duke | melvin    |
```

My `TreeMap` contains:

```
1=> duke, melvin  
2=> duke, melvin  
3=> duke, melvin  
4=> duke, melvin
```

Instead of (as I wanted)

```
1=> joe, lewis 
2=> mark, spencer 
3=> mike, carter 
4=> duke melvin
```

Can anyone point me out where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects in Java are passed around as references, so you are in fact adding the same list for all the keys in your map.

Since you clear it at every step and then add some values to it, it will contain just the last row, after the while loop has finished.

What you really want to do is to create an instance of `ArrayList` for every row and add that to your map, instead of clearing the values in the old one:

```
while (rs.next()) 
{
   listaValores = new ArrayList<String>();

   for(int i = 2; i <= ncolunas; i++)
   {
       listaValores.add(rs.getString(i));
   }

   tmValores.put(rs.getInt(1), listaValores);   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe you have to reassign the value of `listaValores`.

Simply change

```
 listaValores.clear();
```

to

```
 listaValores = new ArrayList<String>();
```